# Why is a documented NSDateFormatter init method not getting recognized?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsdateformatter

I'm getting this warning (below) when trying to use NSDateFormatter. I am importing  in my .h file so what is the prob? (Oh, and the same method generates an error (*unrecognized selector sent...*))

Here is the WARNING:

```
warning: no '-initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:' method found
```

Here is the Code:

```
NSDateFormatter *myFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormat:@"EEE, dd, MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ" allowNaturalLanguage:NO];

NSDate *date = [myFormatter dateFromString:@"Mon, 01 Feb 2010 20:25:37 +0000"];
NSLog(@"Time interval %d",[date timeIntervalSinceNow]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Georg says,  initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage is allowed only on Mac OS X and not on iPhone.

You can use NSDateFormatter on iPhone like this:

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-d-M";
```

Further reading:

- [NSDate Class Reference (iOS)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [Date Formatters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

The [iPhone SDK](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) hasn't got this init method, only the Mac OS X SDK has it. You have to use plain *[[.. alloc] init]* and set the properties yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think it should be...

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];    
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-d-M"];
```