# NSDateFormatter missing methods...am I missing an import

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm an IOS newbie but am trudging forward as best as I can.

I searched this site and google but found no answer to my problem, or even any parallel.

I am using a method declared in the documentation (I actually borrowed this line from a website on obtaining the timezone offset in hours):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormat:@"zzz" allowNaturalLanguage:NO];
```

But the compiler error message says:

> No visible @interface for 'NSDateFormatter' declares the selector 'initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:'

When I try the autocomplete, it does not suggest this particular `init` method, only `init` and `initWithCoder`.

Am I missing some required import? I thought this was a part of the `Foundation.h`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Jason

Comment: I'm extremely curious as to how you set up your Xcode project.

Comment: What in particular would you like to know, trudyscousin? I pretty much followed the defaults in setting up a Single View Application.

Comment: rmaddy pretty much nailed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `NSDateFormatter initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:` is not part of iOS. That method is only available for the Mac. For iOS do:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"zzz"];
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I guess I need to be more careful when looking at the documentation.

Comment: In the Xcode Organizer, under Documentation, make sure you only have the iOS docs selected and not the OS X docs (assuming you are only developing for iOS).

Answer (score 2):

You are getting

```
No visible @interface for 'NSDateFormatter' declares the selector 'initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:'
```

because iOS does not support this selector. Only OS X.

Explained in more detail in this post:
[Why is a documented NSDateFormatter init method not getting recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219948/why-is-a-documented-nsdateformatter-init-method-not-getting-recognized?rq=1)

Also, the Apple Developer Libraries are really helpful. NSDateFormatter Class Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html. It states, "iOS Note: iOS supports only the 10.4+ behavior. 10.0-style methods and format strings are not available on iOS." Link to new formatters: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i